# corporate wiki or CMS for in-house technical reference and document management,

Tags: content-management-system, wiki

We are looking for a CMS/Wiki/DMS to collect and organize technical documentation for technical staff both in head office, and in the field.

Content would be both Wiki style user contributed and vendor/supplier provided (PDF, Word, some Excel)

The particular features we are looking for would include:

- user/password access security (LDAP would be good)
- strong search capabilities - both wiki text and drill-down into PDS, Word & Excel documents. (not sure why, but few web search products seem to offer this)

Answer (score 0):

Give [Daisy](http://www.daisycms.org/) a try. It is easy to install and can [index](http://docs.outerthought.org/daisy-docs-current/373-daisy/18-daisy.html) PDF, PPT, Word, and Excel files